# How to use arrays/lists and loops in Python

Tags: arrays, loops, python-3.x

Ok so this is my first question here. I am currently an IT student and I am taking a fundamentals of programming class. I seem to be spending more time lost and confused than I feel as if I should. We are using Python as the programming language. The topic for this week is arrays and lists. From what I have gathered through reading many other forums, Python does not use array but lists. Therefore the assignment does not make since to me. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Create a FLOWCHART and a STORYBOARD for each problem.

Use the information below to create a storyboard (which can be a text based description for solving the problems) and a flowchart (using flowchart symbols to illustrate how you would program) to solve each problem. You may use Microsoft Word® for your Storyboard and Microsoft PowerPoint® for your flowchart.

1. Problem 1: Create an array that contains the days of the week.
2. Problem 2: Create a loop to print the content above.

So what would the flowchart for this look like? The assignment next week builds on this by actually writing the program in Python. What would the script look like? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to give us something that you've tried.  I'm not going to write code for you.

Comment: My apologies @scottb. I am not asking for someone to write code for me. I am not looking for an easy answer but for someone to point me in the right direction.

days=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']
print(days)

This of course prints the days listed in the list. I am not sure of where the loop that is being requested comes into play.

Comment: I *strongly* suggest reading [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) so you have a basic idea of how to program in Python, what iterating is all about, how to assign things, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @MattDMo. I have used the Python Tutorial in the past. I have 2 weeks left in the course and I have not struggled with any of it up to this point. I have been able to work my way through it either through reference or trial and error. For some reason I seem to have hit a wall with this one.

Comment: [here's](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) some help on `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for hinting, I won't write your program for you. In your comment, you assigned to the list (you're right, they're not called "arrays" in Python) correctly. Now you need to iterate over it to print each item individually. I'd suggest you refresh your memory in the Python Tutorial on how to control program flow, especially the [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) statement. Remember, the general idea is:

```
for item in collection_of_items:
    do_something_with(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
days = ['monday','tuesday','wednessday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday']

for day in days:
    print(day)
```

Edit:

> what would the flowchart for this look like?

This problem is quite simple, try to make your own flowchart. Try to practice thinking at the very first lesson of programming course.

> What would the script look like?

It would look like above code. But you can do it better and more professional, try to figure it out.

Comment: She's trying to learn. Nice job spoon-feeding her everything, without any explanations...

Comment: I read her question carefully, she did investigate about the abstraction of the problem so I think that I don't need to explain more. That's why I just posted that simple code.

Comment: Did you read the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972431/how-to-use-arrays-lists-and-loops-in-python/34972535?noredirect=1#comment57674633_34972431) where she *specifically asked* to not be given the code? No. Downvote stays.

Comment: It's ok for the downvote, because in others point of view  post the code is bad help but in this case I just want to show her that it is very simple don't need to explain too much, just do it.